# Splitting a single large csv file to resample by two columns

Tags: python, csv, android-sensors, resampling, data-preprocessing

I am doing a machine learning project with phone sensor data (accelerometer). I need to preprocess dataset before I export it to the ML model. I have 25 classes (alphabets in the datasets) and there are 20 subjects (how many times I got the alphabet) for each class. Since the lengths are different for each class and subject, I have to resample. I want to split a single csv file by class and subject to be able to resample. I have tried some things like groupby() or other things but did not work. I will be glad if you can share thoughts what I can do about this problem. This is my first time asking a question on this site if I made a mistake I would appreciate it if you warn me about my mistakes. Thank you from now.

I share some code and outputs to help you understand my question better.

[what i got when i tried with groupby() but not exactly what i wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKrxS.png)

￼[This is how my csv file looks like. It contains more than 300,000 data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm8rp.png)

Some code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def read_data(file_path):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    return data

# read csv file
dataset = read_data('raw_data.csv')

df1 = pd.DataFrame( dataset.groupby(['alphabet', 'subject'])['x_axis'].count())
df1['x_axis'].head(20)
```

I also need to do this for every x_axis, y_axis and z_axis so what can I use other than groupby() function? I do not want to use only the lengths but also the values of all three to be able to resample.

Comment: What is `class` and what is `subject`? Also, can you provide a small sample in your question so that one can reproduce on their computers?

Comment: @Epsi95 By class I mean the alphabet in the dataset and the subject is about how many times I got the alphabet. If the alphabet is A and subject is 1, this means the first letter A. Likewise, the alphabet A and subject 2 means the second letter A. I tried to make the letter A and other alphabets in different ways so I need to something like subject to differentiate them. I added some code snippets to improve my question but I guess it was not enough. Thank you for suggestions I will try to improve my question.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why `groupby` is not solving your problem?

Comment: @Epsi95 I want to combine alphabet and subject to do resample. Lengths are different for each class and subject. I want all of them to have same length thats why I want to do resample but since I have a single csv file, I have a hard time trying to split it the way I want. I edit the question you can check it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, calculate the greatest common number of sample

```py
num_sample = df.groupby(['alphabet', 'subject'])['x_axis'].count().min()
```

Now you can sample

```py
df.groupby(['alphabet', 'subject']).sample(num_sample)
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I tried to your code and it worked thank you! Actually I was going to sample using interpolation, but if I use this way, I guess it won't be a big difference. Thank you again.